# How to set prefered libs for Apache TomEE?

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee

I have need to set prefered libs from my project for Apache Tomee. For example, I know there is special weblogic.xml when I can set prefer application resources, in the case with WebLogic Server. I need the same opportunity for Apache Tomee. If be more concrete, I want to override JSF realization (default is MyFaces, but I need Mojarra). In weblogic.xml it looks like this:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
<prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name>
    <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952652/using-a-differnent-version-of-a-jar-than-the-one-supplied-with-tomee/19045120#19045120), you should be able to do it using the System property `openejb.classloader.forced-load`. More information on how to use it on this [ref card](https://tomee.apache.org/refcard/refcard.html)