# Using a differnent version of a jar than the one supplied with Tomee

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee

I am trying to port a web-application to Tomee (Apache TomEE 1.5.2) but I have hit a major hurdle.

The version of quartz our application uses clashes with the bundled version of quartz.

Tomee comes with `quartz-2.1.6.jar` which is loaded as part of the container set-up as far as I can tell, But our application relies on a very old version of Quartz and we are unable to update at this point in time.

From research I had assumed it would be enough to place the older quarts jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` of my web-app and as per the Tomcat class loading information [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) it would be looked up before the `quartz-2.1.6.jar` in the `${catalina.home}/lib` directory, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is it possible for Tomee to use the bundled version of Quartz and my web-app to use a different version of Quartz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Romain Manni-Bucau.

The solution was to add

```
openejb.classloader.forced-load=org.quartz
```

please see [Tomee Users Mailing List](http://openejb.markmail.org/thread/rfixcqxo7aq7kpea)